# Flex style inheriting issue when module include a chart

Tags: apache-flex, module, charts, styles

I meet a problem when migrate the application for flex 3.5 to flex 4.5. The char style cannot be apply correctly when set the style in application, it still use columnChart default style. But when I move the fx:Style declaration to ColumnchChartModule, the char style works. Could someone help me to explain why the style inheriting is broken?

BTW: the button style seems working, when I define a button style in application.

Below is my test code:

```
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"

           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

<fx:Style>

    @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";

    @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";



    .c01 {

        fill: #0D7393;

        areaFill: #0D7393;

    }



    .c02 {

        fill: #A1B26B;

        areaFill: #A1B26B;

    }

    .c03 {

        fill: #C4843D;

        areaFill: #C4843D;

    }

    .c04 {

        fill: #5A4736;

        areaFill: #5A4736;

    }

    .c05 {

        fill: #994C34;

        areaFill: #994C34;

    }

    .c06 {

        fill: #649DA2;

        areaFill: #649DA2;

    }

    .c07 {

        fill: #D66D2B;

        areaFill: #D66D2B;

    }

    .c08 {

        fill: #C8E8B0;

        areaFill: #C8E8B0;

    }

    .c09 {

        fill: #6BB9D3;

        areaFill: #6BB9D3;

    }



    mx|ColumnChart {

        chartSeriesStyles: c01, c02, c03, c04, c05, c06, c07, c08, c09;

    }



    s|Button{

        color: red;

    }

</fx:Style>

<s:layout>

    <s:VerticalLayout />

</s:layout>

<mx:ModuleLoader url="ColumnChartModule.swf" width="100%" height="100%"/>
```

---------------------------------------- ColumnChartModule.mxml

```
       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"

       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="100%" height="100%">

    <fx:Script><![CDATA[

        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

        [Bindable]

        public var expenses:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([

            {Month:"Jan", Revenue:1200, Expenses:500},

            {Month:"Feb", Revenue:1200, Expenses:550},

            {Month:"Mar", Revenue:1240, Expenses:475},

            {Month:"Apr", Revenue:1300, Expenses:600},

            {Month:"May", Revenue:1420, Expenses:575},

            {Month:"Jun", Revenue:1400, Expenses:600},

            {Month:"Jul", Revenue:1500, Expenses:600},

            {Month:"Aug", Revenue:1600, Expenses:750},

            {Month:"Sep", Revenue:1600, Expenses:735},

            {Month:"Oct", Revenue:1750, Expenses:750},

            {Month:"Nov", Revenue:1800, Expenses:800},

            {Month:"Dec", Revenue:2000, Expenses:850}

        ]);



        private function onClick(): void{

            var columnChart:CSSStyleDeclaration = this.styleManager.getStyleDeclaration("mx|ColumnChart");

            var columnChart1:CSSStyleDeclaration = this.styleManager.getMergedStyleDeclaration("mx|ColumnChart");

            var columnChart2:CSSStyleDeclaration = this.styleManager.getStyleDeclaration("s|Button");



            trace(columnChart);

            trace(columnChart1);

            trace(columnChart2);

        }

    ]]></fx:Script>



<s:layout>

    <s:VerticalLayout/>

</s:layout>

<s:Button label="GetChartStyle" click="onClick()" />

<s:Panel title="Floating Column Chart">

    <s:layout>

        <s:VerticalLayout/>

    </s:layout>

    <mx:ColumnChart

        dataProvider="{expenses}"

        showDataTips="true">

        <mx:horizontalAxis>

            <mx:CategoryAxis

                dataProvider="{expenses}"

                categoryField="Month"/>

        </mx:horizontalAxis>

        <mx:series>

            <mx:ColumnSeries

                yField="Revenue"

                displayName="Revenue"/>

            <mx:ColumnSeries

                yField="Expenses"

                displayName="Expenses"/>

        </mx:series>

    </mx:ColumnChart>

</s:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

On your module ie. MyCustomModule.mxml put this override code.

```
override public function get moduleFactory():IFlexModuleFactory{
 return FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.moduleFactory;
}
```